# Disable checkbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, cakephp, checkbox, using

I have two checkboxes, like below:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="id" name="data[Noncompetitor][is_black][1]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" id="id" name="data[Noncompetitor][is_black][2]" value="1">
```

Now, on a condition, I want to disable them using javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work like this:

```
document.getElementById("id").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
```

Re-enable it like this:

```
document.getElementById("id").removeAttribute("disabled");
```

Comment: can we check condition in JS, whether disabled attribute is applied or not ? if yes, how can we check ?

Comment: I thought "id" was just a placeholder in your code. It's not a good practice to have the same id more then once in your document.

Comment: Yes you can check for document.getElementById("id").getAttribute("disabled") == "disabled" for example